# Coldfusion How to save PDF Response Stream to File

Tags: coldfusion

We have a REST API that returns a stream of content-type application/pdf. I just want to save it to a file on the server.

```
<cfhttp url="#ApiPath#" method="post" result="res">
     <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
     <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#payload#" />
</cfhttp>

<cffile  action = "write" file = "#FileName#" output = "#res.fileContent#">
```

I've producing a blank PDF, any ideas? ( ive tried various combinations of cfdocument/cfpdf with no luck)

here's a dump of the REST response:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a dump of the response you get from API call? AFIK `cffile` is writing a simple text file here.

Comment: @RRK done - added a cfdump

Comment: Saving the result directly using chttp's "file", etc attributes didn't work?

Comment: @SOS it did! Updated my answer. If you'd like to submit an answer, i can give you more cred :)

Answer (score 6):

I think I've got it:

**Solution 1:**

```
<cfhttp url="#url#" method="post" result="res">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#payload#" />
</cfhttp>
<cfset bytes  = res.FileContent.toByteArray()>
<cfscript>    
    fos = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init("myfile.pdf");
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
</cfscript>
```

EDIT: Based on SOS's solution this also worked:

**Solution 2:**

```
<cfhttp url="#url#" method="post" result="res" getAsBinary="Auto">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#payload#" />
</cfhttp>

<cfset fileName = listlast(res["responseHeader"]["content-disposition"],";=")>
<cffile action="write" file="#path#\#fileName#" output="#res.FileContent#">
```

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear :-) I meant try using cfhttp to save the response directly, instead of using cffile i.e. `<cfhttp file="filename.pdf"path="c:/somepath" ....>`